# Difference between different ways of malloc

Tags: c, malloc

```
struct node{
  int w;
  int x;
}
struct node *item;
```

1. Please explain the difference between these statements.
2. i read as typecasting after malloc is not needed. why is that so?

   1) `item = malloc(sizeof(*item));`

   2) `item = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

   3) `item = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same. don't use 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: 1) is slightly better IMHO because if for some reason the type of `item` changes to another type of pointer you'll have to change less code.

Comment: Not so!  1) and 3) are fine, 1) is more C-ish, 3) give portability to C++.  Don't use 2) because it is error prone.

Comment: casting return of `malloc()` prevents 3 from being a good choice (this _is_ tagged C).  ***1)*** is probably better of the first two, for the reasons given by @JoelHecht.

Comment: Note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function; you only need to surround the operand in parentheses if the operand is a type name.  So you could write `sizeof *item` or `sizeof (struct node)`.  I prefer the former for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that using the expression `*item` will protect you if someone decides to change the base type (say, from `struct node` to `struct another_node_with_a_different_size`).

Comment: " i read as typecasting after malloc is not needed. why is that so?"  - why would you think it is needed in the first place?  If you try to explain why it is needed you will find yourself unable to come up with anything sensible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, all three are equivalent.

Stylistically, 1 is the preferred option (at least by me and a number of other C programmers).  Note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, and parentheses are only required when the operand is a type name.  So you could write `sizeof *item` as opposed to `sizeof (*item)` - the parens don't hurt anything except readability.  Also note that `sizeof` does not attempt to *evaluate* its argument (it won't try to dereference `item`); all it does is compute the number of bytes required by the resulting type, and it does that at compile time, not run time.

As far as C is concerned, you should *not* cast the result of `malloc`.  As of the 1989 standard it's no longer necessary; `malloc` returns a `void *`, which can be assigned to any other pointer type without needing an explicit cast<sup>1</sup>.

Under the C89 standard, casting the result of `malloc` could suppress a useful diagnostic if you forgot to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise didn't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope.  C89 still allowed implicit `int` declarations; if the compiler saw a function call in the code without a declaration, it assumed the function returned an `int` value.  If you left off the cast, the compiler would complain that you were trying to assign an integer value to a pointer object.  With the cast, the compiler would compile the code without a diagnostic, but you'd be converting a pointer value to an `int` and back to a pointer again, which may or may not work.

The C99 standard got rid of implicit `int` declarations, so that isn't a problem anymore; cast or not, you'll get a diagnostic if you forget to include `stdlib.h`.  You should still leave the cast off for readability and maintainability reasons; all it does is add useless visual clutter.  If you change the declaration of the target (from `struct foo *` to `struct bar *`), then you'd have to update the cast as well, which is just extra work, and if you forget to do it then it's a bug.  `item = malloc( sizeof *item )` will *always* do the right thing without any further maintenance, no matter what changes you make to the type of `item`.

C++, being a different language from C with different rules, does *not* allow you to assign a `void *` to another pointer type without an explicit cast, so you *would* have to cast the result of `malloc` in that case.  This is an issue if you're migrating from C to C++ and haven't redone all your dynamic memory management code (which is the *only* excuse for using `malloc` in C++ code). As a matter of course, you should *not* use `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` in C++; either use one of the standard containers, or use the `new` operator.

---

<sup>1 - Prior to the C89 standard, `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all returned `char *`, so a cast *was* required if the target was a different pointer type.  Unfortunately, the habit persisted even though it was no longer necessary</sup>

Answer (score 2):

All methods will give you exactly the same result in this particular case.

1:

`item = malloc(sizeof(*item));`

`*item` is a `struct node`, therefore `sizeof(*item)` will return the size of a `struct node`, and the line will allocate memory for a single node. This is sometimes to be preferred to 2), as if you were to refactor `item` to be a different type, you do not need to change this line.

2:

`item = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

This line is fairly self-explanatory. As mentioned before, though, if `item` were to change type, you would need to change this line as the amount of memory allocated will no longer be correct (except, perhaps, by pure luck).

3:

`malloc` returns a pointer to `void`, or `void *`. This is automatically converted to the proper type even without a cast. In fact, several people (myself included) will advise you strongly not to use the typecast ever. For more details, read the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @ wolfPack88
How can *item be a data type . item is initially a pointer to nothing. Even if had pointed to something,then by dereferencing it we dont get a data type

Comment: @jaig: Please don't leave an answer when you wish to comment. With that said, to answer your question: It doesn't matter if `item` points to anything or not, as `item` was declared as a `struct node *`, when `*item` is a `struct node`. For example, let's look at `int a = 4; int *b; b = &a;` In this example, `b` is a pointer to `int`, and `*b` evaluates to 4, i.e., `*b` is an `int`. `*b` was an `int` even before the line `b=&a`, but evaluating `*b` would have yielded a garbage result.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at these:

```
1) item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
```

The above code is the classic way in C.  It may be safer to use `calloc` as it will clear to allocated structure to all bits zero. A useful side effect that will save you if you later add fields to the structure and forget to initialize the in the code that follows the `malloc` in every instance of an allocation.  I would so recommend:

```
1 preferred) item = calloc(1, sizeof(*item));
```

The alternative below assumes `item` is a pointer to `struct node`.  It may be true when you first write the code and may become false if you later change the type of `item` or if you copy to code to a different place where `item` is a different type and you forget to make the change.

```
2) item = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The last option exhibits another issue:

```
3) item = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The issue of casting the return value of `malloc` has been commented a lot elsewhere.  It is necessary in C++ and considered useless and potentially error prone in C.  There is a context in which it may actually serve a good purpose:

```
#define alloc_node()  ((struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(node)))

item = alloc_node();
```

Here it is advisable to use the cast in order to detect allocations of the wrong type.  If `item` is not a pointer to a `struct node`, the compiler will complain and prevent the bug.

In conclusion, prefer `calloc` over `malloc`, and prefer `sizeof(*item)` over `sizeof(node node)`.  If the context does not allow to use `sizeof(*dst)`, as above or within an expression or a function argument, then use the cast.

Comment: the macro one is really a very bad style. it hides a lot of essential things without providing any convenience. preferred way: `#define ALLOC_NODE(var) struct node *var = malloc(sizeof *var)`.

Comment: `alloc_node()` is a poor man's inline function without side affects.  Your proposal will fail on very simple cases: `ALLOC_NODE(*array)`.  The naive user will have a hard time understanding what went wong ;-)

Comment: Also, I am not advocating the use of this macro, I am insisting on the use of the cast in this case.

Comment: that's not true. my style happens every where in linux kernel code. every interface has its usage and mine does too. in c, casting `malloc` is generally not recommended. there was a big discussion in my link in the comment.

Comment: You are missing the point.  If the context does not allow for syntax 1), using the cast will catch type mismatches that will go unnoticed with syntax 2).   The discussion is very interesting, it shows there are good reasons for both syntaxes, depending on context. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc )

Comment: Consider variation on style 1) `item = malloc(sizeof *item);` - dropped unneeded `()`.

Comment: Indeed parentheses are only required for types and `sizeof` has the precedence of all prefix operators.  This set of extra parentheses does not hurt and as, a matter of personal taste, looks more consistent to me.  I never type spaces between monadic operators and their operand, and dont want to bend this stylistic rule for `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

Form 2 is bad because you may accidentally allocate the wrong amount of memory.

Form 1 and Form 3 both allow the programmer to do a visual check that allocation is correct:

```
   item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
// ^^^^                 ^^^^^

   item = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Once you learn that `varname` should go with `*varname`, or that `(Typename *)` should go with `(Typename)`, then you are more likely to quickly detect size errors.

As explained on [the main thread about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), in C89 Form 3 was dangerous whereas Form 1 was safe. In C99 and later that rationale is less compelling, however Form 1 has the benefits of being more compact, and requiring less maintenance. If the type of `item` is changed then any Form 3 lines will trigger a compilation error, whereas Form 1 lines will just automatically work correctly with the updated type.